# Upgrade to WebSocket is required. Error when browse to folder api messages for bot deployed in azure

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created a LivePerson Bot for handoff as per sample code. It works fine when I run it locally from emulator but. When I deploy it in azure, My messages from Liveperson agent to Azure Bot are not reaching to bot. At the same time I also get the error "Upgrade to WebSocket is required" when I browse URL api/messages of a deployed bot. Can anybody help me here. What can be probalble reasons?

Live Person proxy bot sample can be found here.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples/LivePersonProxyAssistant

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check this setting in the WebApp configuration:

[image]

Comment: Hi Miguel Veloso,

Web Socket option is "On" status already, as you have highlighted. Still I am getting this error.

Comment: Did you add the WebSockets support middleware to the webapp? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-the-middleware